# Installing spice3f5 circuit simulator on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mac, simulator

I am looking to install spice3f5 or similar on my Mac OSX but I cannot find clear steps on how to do it. I am not looking for MacSpice 3 or ngSpice but spice3f5. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The documentation on this software is great.  This piece of software is suppose to work on OS X correct?

Comment: This software is meant to run on UNIX based systems so I assume it would run on mac osx. There is documentation but there are no installation steps specific to mac.